# How to resolve "The item you were attempting to purchase could not be found", for app, not in app purchases?

Tags: android, google-play, coronasdk

When we uploaded our game to the Google Play store, we got that error message. The game is free, and has no in app purchases. All other questions are concerning in-app purchases. We had someone not linked to our publishing account try, and he got the same result. We built the game with Corona SDK, not sure if this matters. The apk is signed for release and does install, just not through the store. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, we just tried to download it as soon as the listing showed up. All we had to do was wait.